# Encriptar en Angular y desencriptar en PHP con AES

Tags: php, javascript, angular, typescript, encriptación

Estoy encriptando una cadena del lado de Angular con la librería crypto-js para luego poder desencriptarla en PHP. Tras mucho buscar por foros no encuentro la forma de desencriptar la cadena que genera este codigo typescript utilizando PHP.
Si alguien supiese como hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho.

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

encrypt(value : string) : string {
   var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567890123456');
   var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
   var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
      iv: iv
   });

   return iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}
```

Comment: no veo el problema ambas solo usan funciones javascript; Checa este ejemplo: https://embed.plnkr.co/0VPU1zmmWC5wmTKPKnhg/   Solo debes asegurarte que en ambos sitios contengas los mismos parametros: salero, pass, tipo de cifrado, etc.

Comment: La desencriptación tiene que ser en lenguaje PHP, ahí es donde encuentro el problema. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: puedes crear un servicio de encriptacion/descencriptacion en php para que sea consumido por tu codigo javascript.